# setImageBitmap() / NullpointerException

Tags: android, bitmap, nullpointerexception, imageview

I'm trying to download and show an image with `Bitmap` and `ImageView`.
I'm using an `AsyncTask` which takes `url` and `view` as arguments but I always get a

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a null object reference
```

doInBackground:

```
protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Log.d("MyActivity", url.toString());
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap res = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            is.close();
            if(res!= null)
                Log.d("MyActivity", "I'm here");
            return res;
        } catch(IOException ioe){

        }
        return null;
    }
```

onPostExecute:

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
       ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        if(bitmap == null)
            Snackbar.make(view, "Error", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        else if(bitmap instanceof Bitmap) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            Snackbar.make(view, "Downloaded", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view you are passing to your asynctask does not contain an ImageView with the R.id.imageView id, so when you try find that ImageView within the View you are getting a null ImageView. Then, when invoke setImageBitmap method, you get a nullPointerException because of you ImageView == null.

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
if(null == imageView) {
  Log.e("Error", "Ouh! there is no there is no child view with R.id.imageView ID within my parent view View.");
}
```

Try the code above and you will see printed the error in your LogCat.